# Notating timestamp in writing about music

Tags: time, music

I was wondering what is more commonly accepted in academic writing about music. I was using 1:00 to notate the minute and second mark something is happening in a track (for example, a new section starts at 2:05, or it is drums only from 1:00 to 1:23) and I thought the context would be clear that it is M:SS and not H:MM. But I'm not sure, should I use the prime tick marks to indicate M′SS″ instead?

Thanks!

Comment: If the piece is over one hour, use HH:MM:SS, If it is less than an hour, use MM:SS

Comment: To find the correct format, the best option would be to consult the style guide you are meant to follow, and if that doesn't make it clear, look how other documents handle it. Without external guidance, the most important thing is to be consistent.